# How to access a server on VMware from the web?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, apache-http-server, vmware

Here's what I have done:

- I set up an `apache` server on `Ubuntu` in `VMware`.
- I used the `NAT` config.
- I set up port forwarding.

[image]

Now on the host machine, I can access the server using `localhost`. It works.
But from the web, if I use the Host's `IP address` in another computer, I cannot access the web server.

Is there anything more I need to do?

Comment: He asked about connecting to the guest from the host. I want to connect to the guest from another computer on the web.

Comment: could you elaborate on the port forwarding you did?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the port forwarding settings

Comment: I think you're confusing 'the web' - more correctly http/https and maybe https2. Also, you might be behind *double* nat - you may also need to port forward from whatever's between the wider internet and your vmware workstation/player install.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this `you may also need to port forward from whatever's between the wider internet and your vmware workstation`

Comment: I don't know your setup. If you have a router, it needs port forwarding too. And that's assuming that your ISP hasn't blocked port 80. My suggestion would be to try another system in the same lan as your vmware host first. Then try it from the internet. And test with a less common port too, I like 9180.